# Trigger a task on file Creates/Edits/Deletes in specific folder (AWS FSx)

Tags: amazon-web-services, event-log, windows-task-scheduler, amazon-fsx

I have a network path from AWS FSx (Already allowed Auditing from Folder's Advance Security Settings).
I need to log file Create/Delete/Edit on that network path from my server(Windows).

I tried to create a Custom view on Windows Event Viewer with event ID 4663.
[image]

But the problem is, that it shows logs from other folders as well.
I want to filter only the events from my network path and trigger a windows task, based on that Custom event view.

Answer (score 0):

As it was a bit complicated to catch the detailed event from AWS, I changed the approach to accomplish my task.
I created a background worker to track all file changes in the given folder
using .Net [Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-7.0), [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0) and [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0) classes.